# raspberry pi sense hat calibration not working

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to use a raspberry pi with a sense hat, ran RTIMULibCal, and put the RTIMULib.ini file into the folder containing my python code (I also found a guide telling me to put it to /etc, so I copied it there as well). I tried the compass program that I downloaded as a part of this repository: https://github.com/RPi-Distro/python-sense-hat.git
(it's in the examples folder), but the blue dot is not moving at all. I tried to print out get_compass() and get_compass_raw(), and got values between 130 and 150 for get_compass(), between -80 and -40 for y, between -70 and -40 for x, and between -60 and 30 for z, so it seems like a calibration error to me. Did anyone have a similar problem, or has any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Go with the instruction for solve the problem:

Install the necessary software and run the calibration program as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave -y
cd
cp /usr/share/librtimulib-utils/RTEllipsoidFit ./ -a
cd RTEllipsoidFit
RTIMULibCal
```

press **m** and follow the instruction (I also used **e**).

More information https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/sense-hat/

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. The key thing was to replace the RTIMULib.ini from the .config/sense_hat folder (for some reason the guides I have read previously skipped this part and said to put it in my current working directory, so python used a wrong calibration file). Thank you again.